# Update fields using Sitecore Powershell Extensions

Tags: powershell-extensions, language-fallback

I'm using the following script to update a specific field in all the children of the item right-clicked in my content tree. It works but the update is not applied to the item clicked with my context menu. It is only applied to children.

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse . | Where-Object { $_.Fields["__Enable item fallback"] -ne $null } | ForEach-Object {

    $_.Editing.BeginEdit()
    $_.Fields["__Enable item fallback"].Value = "1";
    $_.Editing.EndEdit()

}
```

Comment: You are calling Get-ChildItem cmdlet that's why update is only applied to children. You should do the same also with Get-Item cmdlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet that's why update is only applied to children. You should do the same also with `Get-Item` cmdlet to make it work also for current item.

Should be like this:

```
$item = Get-Item .
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item.Fields["__Enable item fallback"].Value = "1"
$item.Editing.EndEdit()
```

`.` is representing current item.

How to add custom task in context menu with SPE:

https://www.sitecorenutsbolts.net/2016/11/01/Right-Click-Unlock-Item-with-Sitecore-PowerShell-Extensions/

See more about supported cmdlets here:

https://blog.najmanowicz.com/2014/10/12/working-with-sitecore-items-in-powershell-extensions/

Comment: Thank you ! How can i get the path to item ? 
The item in question is clicked with the context menu

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: I've used the $SitecoreContextItem variable which works perfectly ! thank you for your help

Answer (score 8):

Since version 4.0, Sitecore PowerShell Extensions includes a `-WithParent` parameter to the `Get-ChildItem` command. This includes the item itself, thus making this much simpler:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse . -WithParent |
  Where-Object { $_.Fields["__Enable item fallback"] -ne $null } |
  ForEach-Object {
    $_.Editing.BeginEdit()
    $_.Fields["__Enable item fallback"].Value = "1";
    $_.Editing.EndEdit()
  }
```

Sources:

- [Release Notes](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/releases.html#version-40)
- [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/580)
- I've used it extensively

Comment: Ooh never saw the -WithParent parameter before - that's really useful to know!

Answer (score 4):

@chorpo hit the nail on the head, `Get-ChildItem` does not get current item, but the children underneath the current Item.  You will need to do a `Get-Item` as well to get/update the values of the current item.  You should be able to kill two birds with one stone by getting both children and current items and appending:

```
$path = "."
$root = Get-Item $path
$items = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse
($items += $root) | Where-Object { $_.Fields["__Enable item fallback"] -ne $null } | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Editing.BeginEdit()
    $_.Fields["__Enable item fallback"].Value = "1";
    $_.Editing.EndEdit()
}
```